# how to echo same key value first after other key value from multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, grouping

I have get data from array and I have get same key value data first than other key value in multidimensional array.

My array result like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 113
            [timeIn] => 10:40:11
            [timeOut] => 10:53:13
            [hour] => 00:13:00
            [emp_id] => 42

)


    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 114
            [timeIn] => 15:18:57
            [timeOut] => 15:00:00
            [hour] => 04:19:00
            [emp_id] => 42

   )
)  ......
```

I have first get timeIn and timeOut record from all than echo other key.

How to do from any method or loop in php?

I expected result like this

```
10:40:11 10:53:13
15:18:57 15:00:00
42
00:13:00 04:19:00
```

Comment: can you update question with full multidimensional array (with key and values) ? or can you get `emp_id` outside array result?

Comment: @nick this is single emp_id multiple record in same say

Comment: @ManishaPatel sorry - missed those values...

Comment: What does entry 2 of the array look like? It makes a big difference to the answer...

Comment: timein,timeout,hour entry are diffrent in same day=>those entry are one and more than one time possible., i have make report for same emp_id all timein and timeout entry echo first

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e18a5003af46293c412903962a31edd4ad0472cf).

**Code**

```
$array = [
    [
        [
            "id" => 113,
            "timeIn" => "10:40:11",
            "timeOut" => "10:53:13",
            "hour" => "00:13:00",
            "emp_id" => 42
        ],
        [
            "id" => 114,
            "timeIn" => "15:18:57",
            "timeOut" => "15:00:00",
            "hour" => "04:19:00",
            "emp_id" => 42
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "id" => 113,
            "timeIn" => "10:40:11",
            "timeOut" => "10:53:13",
            "hour" => "00:13:00",
            "emp_id" => 43
        ],
        [
            "id" => 114,
            "timeIn" => "15:18:57",
            "timeOut" => "15:00:00",
            "hour" => "04:19:00",
            "emp_id" => 43
        ]
    ]
];

foreach($array as $val){

    foreach($val as $time){
        echo $time['timeIn'] . ' ' . $time['timeOut'] . "\n";
    }
    echo $time['emp_id'] ."\n";
    echo $val[0]['hour'] . ' ' . $val[1]['hour'] . "\n\n";
}
```

**Result**

```
10:40:11 10:53:13
15:18:57 15:00:00
42
00:13:00 04:19:00

10:40:11 10:53:13
15:18:57 15:00:00
43
00:13:00 04:19:00
```

Comment: Your input structure is not guaranteed to be the same as OPs as they don't show that much.

Comment: bluetree@this is multi dimensional array so not a fix number of keys value, so how i can dynamoc $val[1]['hour']; etc field key value?

Comment: @ManishaPatel This is multi-dimensional array. I just used fixed data just to show an example. Will you get more than 2  array inside of your posted array?